# How do I know the correct encoding when I calling BaseFont.createFont() with itext?

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I have some custom Chinese font files:

```
aaa.ttf
bbb.ttf
ccc.ttf
```

And I want to use them to create my pdf with iText.

This is the code I use to create a `BaseFont`:

```
String encoding = ???
BaseFont messageBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("fonts/aaa.ttf", 
                               encoding, 
                               BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

But I don't know how to find the `encoding`. Take `aaa.ttf` for example:

[image]

Can I find the `encoding` from the information? I tried some encodings like `BaseFont.CP1252` or `BaseFont.WINANSI`, but they didn't work, the output are blank page or a lot of `??????` characters if they are Chinese characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are different answers to this question. For a full overview, you could read chapter 11 of my book, "iText in Action", but if you just want to be safe, use Identity-H for horizontal text (and Identity-V). This isn't really an encoding, but it will create a composite font in the PDF that uses Unicode: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#IDENTITY_H

Comment: Thanks for your help, the creator of itext. I just tried `IDENTITY_H`, and found the characters can be displayed correctly in pdf.